# react parsing error: unexpected error '#' while using the react router sitemap npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am trying to build a sitemap using react-router-sitemap npm.I installed all the npms regarding react-router-sitemap and also created a sitemap-generator.js file. I wrote the following code.

router.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
function Routes() {
  return (
    <Route>
      <Route exact path="/" />
      <Route path="/PrivacyPolicy" />
      <Route path="/TermsAndConditions" />
      <Route path="/AboutUs" />
      <Route path="/Pricing" />
      <Route path="/CancellationPolicy" />
      <Route path="/ContactUs" />
    </Route>
  );
}
export default Routes;
```

sitemap-generator.js:

```
require("babel-register")({
  presets: ["es2015", "react"]
});
const router = require("./router");
const Sitemap = require("react-router-sitemap").default;
function generateSitemap() {
  return (
    new Sitemap(router)
        .build("https://www.example.com")
        .save("./public/sitemap.xml")
  );
}
generateSitemap();
```

I am running the file as node `sitemap-generator.js` . On execution am facing the error as `unexpected character '#'.
SyntaxError: /home/vamshir/Documents/workspace/merritos-scroll/src/App.css: Unexpected character '#' (1:12)`

> 1 | html, body, #root, .App{
>       |             ^
>     2 |   height: 100%;
>     3 | }

Please can anybody help me with the solution.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Replace this statement `const router = require("./App");` with `const router = require("./App.js");`

Comment: @ Niraj Kaushal Thanks for your response!  I have tried with that case also but still am facing the  same error.

Comment: change your css file name and check it. Because both are same name.also check app.js file is there your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You are importing wrong module in this statement `const router = require("./App");` in sitemap-generator.js file, replace this line with `const router = require("./router");`

---

As mentioned on `react-router-sitemap`,

> You need to have a module with the router configuration.

You have to create a route configuration file `router.js`(file name is upto you) and inside that file configuration will be similar to following code,

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

export default (
    <Route>
        <Route path='/' />
        <Route path='/about' />
        <Route path='/projects' />
        <Route path='/contacts' />
        <Route path='/auth' />
    </Route>
);
```

And then require this file and assign it to `router`. [For more details](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-sitemap)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried with that case but am finding only my domain url.I am not getting all the url paths of  my website.   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url> <loc>https://www.example.com/</loc> </url>
</urlset>

Comment: You may have only one route defined in the route page. Add some more routes and related pages and then generate sitemap.

Comment: Thanks!As mentioned above, I have added all the routes of my website to router.js file.Still am not getting all the url paths of my website.import React from 'react';
import {
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <Route>
    <Route exact path="/" />
    <Route path="/PrivacyPolicy" />
    <Route path="/TermsAndConditions" />
    <Route path="/AboutUs" />
    <Route path="/Pricing" />
    <Route path="/CancellationPolicy" />
    <Route path="/ContactUs" />
    </Route>
  );
}
export default App;

Comment: Please update your question with latest code. Both router.js and sitemap-generator.js

Comment: Thanks! I have replaced the line in sitemap-generator.js  as const router = require("./router");in my code but I forgot to edit the question in this forum.But still am unable to get the all url paths of my website .

Answer (score 0):

I think it gets another files from that directory you need to add these lines to your top of  sitemap-generator.js

```
  require.extensions[(".css", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".scss")] = function () {
  return null;
};
```

I had same erorr but after adding these lines it did not give that error  any more .It gives another error now .
But I recomend to you try it